# Changes are not saved in the Core Data Model (ex. delete object)

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, save

I have a tableviewcontroller which displays the objects of a Core Data model. I have a button in its navigation bar that when clicked it deletes the row and the object in the model. For the test purpose, in the AppDelegate I add an object with 2 attributes to the models only entity. Then I am displaying this object in the tableview. On delete button click the selected row is deleted and I ve set it to delete the object also from the data model, but it won't save the changes. Every time I rebuild and run the application even more will be added, while when I delete them, the changes won't stay till the next rebuild. How can I fix this in my code?

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "favTable.h"


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSManagedObject *favoritesInfo;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) favTable *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *favoritesInfo;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;


- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory; // reference files for core data


@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
@synthesize navController = _navController;

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize favoritesInfo;



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{



    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    favoritesInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                                       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FavoritesInfo"
                                       inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [favoritesInfo setValue:@"Product 1" forKey:@"name"];
    [favoritesInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:15] forKey:@"score"];


    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }





    return YES;
}

// Core Data methods

- (void)saveContext{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataModel.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}


@end
```

**favtable.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>



@interface favTable : UITableViewController  <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> 
{
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
   NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

    NSArray *favArr;
    NSMutableArray *favName;


}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *favArr;


@property (strong, nonatomic) ScannedProductControllerViewController *spVC;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *favName;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ecoViewController *mainController;

@end
```

**favtable.m**

```
#import "favTable.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@interface favTable ()

@end

@implementation favTable

@synthesize favArr;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize favName;




- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Favorites";


    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

    UIBarButtonItem *delButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Del"
                                  style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                  target: self
                                  action:@selector(delItemToArray)];


    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = delButton;


    // passing the array of addedtofavorites to the total one with all favorites


    self.managedObjectContext = ((AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).managedObjectContext;



    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"FavoritesInfo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", nil]];



      NSError *error=nil;

    self.favArr=[[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];


    if (error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@" fetchError=%@,details=%@",error,error.userInfo); 
    }


    self.favName = self.favName = [[self.favArr valueForKey:@"name"]mutableCopy];



}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [favName count];;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;

         // Configure the cell...

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell... setting the text of our cell's label

    cell.textLabel.text = [favName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}



//Delete Item To Array
- (void)delItemToArray {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    AppDelegate *appDelegatee = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [context deleteObject:appDelegatee.favoritesInfo];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath;
    [favName removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [appDelegatee saveContext]; // to save changes

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error deleting movie, %@", [error userInfo]);
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Is it happening in rebuilds only, or the same thing happens if you actually *use* the app in the device/simulator and exit it using the home button or killing it and re-entering it?

Comment: When I rebuild it. Instead of adding just one object, it adds up the objects, while it does not keep track of the delete changes. But when I just exit and renter the changes are saved

Comment: How about when you double press the home button and kill the app from app switcher and then re-open it? I think it's an expected behavior that happens when you rebuild the app. What matters is that it shouldn't happen when you kill the app and run it again.

Comment: When i completely delete the app it just starts from the normal state of having one object added in one row. When I just rerun the app it keeps adding one more object while it ignores the delete action in the next run. When I just exit the app using the home menu button it keeps the changes properly when i go back in

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *deleting the app*? Deleting the process, or deleting the whole app from device completely?

Comment: the whole app from device. when i just exit the tableviewcontroller and reenter the changes won't be kept

Comment: That's obvious that it is going to happen! You're expecting the app to save non-existent content?!! Download and install any app from the store and then remove it from your device; go back and re-install it. Do you expect your old data show up for you all of a sudden!?!?

Comment: No of course not. My problem is that when I exit the app (not deleting it) the changes won't be kept. I delete an object/row but if i re-enter the change won't exist

Answer (score -1):

There are so many problems with your code, I do not know where to begin.

*Class names should start with Capital letters.

You are using two variables for the same app delegate singleton in FavTable.m.

You are declaring a variable `indexPath` without initializing it.

The reloading of the table view should be handled in the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods.
You are apparently not using the fetched results controller. Why?
Your mutable array `favName` has a confusing name, contributing to the general lack of readability.

You write Dadaist statements such as `self.favName = self.favName`...

Your button handler method name `delItemToArray` is similarly adventurous.

`favArr` is an immutable array, but you assign an mutable one to it.

`favName` and `favArr` are redundant because `favArr` already contains all the information.

You are modifying `favName` during delete but are not reacting to data changes. 
The app delegate has no business keeping a reference to `favoritesInfo`.

etc... etc...*

In short, you are way over you head with this. You should invest some time in acquiring some basic programming skills before tackling Objective-C and Core Data.

Comment: I didn't present the complete code and tried to simplify it which caused most of the issues you raised. I am aware that I am not advanced as I only recently started learning objective-c. I am interested in core-data and not the basics though. I hope you can respect that. No need for show off